# Residue fields of $\mathrm{Spec} \ \mathbf{Z}[T]$.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $f\in\mathbf{Z}[T]$ be an irreducible polynomial, and $p=(f)$. The residue field $k(p)$ at $p$ is the fraction field of $\mathbf{Z}[T]/(f)$. *Is every algebraic number field equal to some $k(p)$?* I can't come up with counterexamples, because the number fields I know (such as the cyclotomic fields) are of this form. I think a relevant observation is that a ring of integers cannot always be generated by one element, but I don't think that this yields the answer is no (it might suggest it, though).

I do understand, however, that all finite fields are of the form $k(p)$ for some maximal ideal $p$. (I came up with this question while playing around, this is not a homework question or anything.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is an algebraic number field then by the [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem) there exists some element $\theta\in K$ for which $K=\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$. Let $m(T)$ be the minimal polynomial for $\theta$. Then the fraction field of $\mathbb{Z}[\theta]\cong\mathbb{Z}[T]/(m(T))$ will be $K=\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$.

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't [give much details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem#Constructive_results) on the proof. How should I convince myself that for every $a,b \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, there exists $c \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(a,b) = \mathbb{Q}(c)$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 When you googled "primitive element theorem" and looked up one of the pdfs with proofs in the top few results, what was the first part you didn't understand?

Comment: @user1952009 If I really needed to I could probably remember/reconstruct the proof. The main trick is already highlighted on Wikipedia, but you said it's short on details, and these details are provided by many of the pdfs if you just google it. It is a standard result that should be in all textbooks on Field theory or Galois theory by the way.

Comment: [There](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~kbrown/6310/primitive.pdf) they say that : with $f(x),g(x)$ the minimal polynomials of $a,b$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, with $c = a+\lambda b, \lambda \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $P(x)$ the minimal polynomial of $b$ over $\mathbb{Q}(c)$, we have that $P$ divides both $g$ and $h(x) = f(c-\lambda x)$

Comment: @user1952009 Yes - now, what can you say about the degree of $ \gcd(g, h) $?

Comment: @Starfall They continue with $P(b') = 0 \implies g(b') = 0$ and $ f(a') = 0$ with $a' = c-\lambda b'$. But this means $\lambda = \frac{a-a'}{b - b'}$ (where $a',b'$ are roots of $f,g$) and there are only finitely many such $\lambda$. Therefore, for almost every $\lambda \in \mathbb{Q}$, we have that $P$ has only one root : $ b$ and hence $\mathbb{Q}(a,b) = \mathbb{Q}(a+\lambda b)$

Comment: When I think about it, how do we actually know that the minimal polynomial has coefficients in $\mathbf{Z}$?

Comment: @syzygy If $\theta$'s minpoly is $m(T)$, then $n\theta$'s minpoly is $n^{\deg m}m(T/n)$, which will have integer coefficients if $n$ is divisible by all denominators of all coefficients of $m(T)$. Since scaling $\theta$ by an integer doesn't change $\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$, without loss of generality we may assume $m(T)$ has integer coefficients.